# Creating a tensor of ordered integers of shape (None, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given an input batch of size (None, 1), is it possible to create a tensor of ordered integers that is the same shape?

ex:

```
input = [3, 2, 3, 7], output = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

ex:

```
input = [9, 3, 12, 4, 34 .....], output = [0, 1, 2, 3, ....]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.range()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) does what you need, you just need to provide the size based on the size of your input tensor. Because people already told you this, I will show you another approach.

[`tf.cumsum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cumsum) on the ones vector:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None))
y = tf.cumsum(tf.ones_like(x)) - 1


with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(y, {x: [4, 3, 2, 6, 3]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
op = tf.range(tf.size(x))[:,tf.newaxis]

# test with different sizes
sess.run(op, {x: np.expand_dims(range(10), axis=-1)})
sess.run(op, {x: np.expand_dims(range(3), axis=-1)})
```